# Error when using nested selects in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a simple exercise for slq where i have to get as much info as i can about poeple who work in japan in my database. However i just started learning so i don't even know what to google to answer my problem. So here it is:

My Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 
    (SELECT *
    FROM Departments
    WHERE LOCATION_ID = 
        (SELECT *
        FROM Locations
        WHERE Country_ID = 
            (SELECT *
            FROM Countries
            WHERE Country_Name = 'Japan')))
```

My Error:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with     EXISTS.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

My Database:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0aT.png

EDIT: I think i hit a wall... https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjTps.png

Comment: This looks like a potential performance nightmare. You should reconsider rewriting this with joins.

Comment: I did hear something about joins, however i am not concerned about performance as no tables have more than 100 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `select *` in your nested selects. You need to select a particular column instead.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
    FROM Departments
    WHERE LOCATION_ID IN 
        (SELECT LOCATION_ID
        FROM Locations
        WHERE Country_ID IN 
            (SELECT Country_ID
            FROM Countries
            WHERE Country_Name = 'Japan')))
```

The same query using `JOINS` which are efficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Departments ON Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN Locations ON Departments.LOCATION_ID = Locations.Location_ID
INNER JOIN Countries ON Locations.Country_ID = Countries.Country_ID
WHERE Countries.Country_Name = 'Japan'
```

Comment: @Kevin:- Also do note that I have used `IN` instead of `=` as I assume that queries can return more than one row. Thanks :)

Comment: You are right that they retuen more than one row, i tried it with = and i got "Subquery returned more than 1 value." Error. However i am not getting any results when i try it with IN.

Comment: @Kevin:- I suggest you to better use JOINS instead of nested selects

Comment: I heard about joins before but i didn't look into them yet, is there a way to do it without them, not a big deal just curious.

Comment: @Kevin:- Updated my answer using JOINS. Please verify

Comment: @Kevin:- hahahaha...You should have checked that ;) Anyways insert the data and enjoy. And yes do try to use the JOIN query instead of nested selects. Its a good practice. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, at least now i know whats wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "SELECT * " inside IN statements. Change your query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
    FROM Departments
    WHERE LOCATION_ID = 
        (SELECT LOCATION_ID
        FROM Locations
        WHERE Country_ID = 
            (SELECT Country_ID
            FROM Countries
            WHERE Country_Name = 'Japan')))
```

Comment: I didnt know that it would be a problem becuase i dont know the limitations of = but i get an error because i am returning mor than one row.

Comment: Change the "=" to IN R.T. found it first. Props.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Select the ID instead of * on the Subqueries. You should definitely learn to write it out this way so you know how to use subqueries. However in reality for this type of query you should be using JOINs. Here's an example of how to do it that way:

`SELECT Employees.*
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Departments
    ON Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN Locations
    ON Departments.LOCATION_ID = Locations.Location_ID
INNER JOIN Countries
    ON Locations.Country_ID = Countries.Country_ID
WHERE Countries.Country_Name = 'Japan'`

Answer (score 0):

I would write it using joins. Much cleaner.

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    Employees e
        JOIN Departments d ON e.Department_ID = d.id
        JOIN Locations l ON d.location_id = l.id
        JOIN Countries c ON l.country_id = c.id
WHERE   c.Country_Name = 'Japan'
```